# Rav Yosef Karo's Kesef Mishneh: is there online an English translation?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, commentaries, english, mishneh-torah

Do you know of online an  English translation of  Rav Yosef Karo's Kesef Mishneh? Unless I'm mistaken, it is a fundamental work to better understand the Mishneh Torah.

Comment: This is potentially a project for artscroll as they have translated many essential english works, maybe contact them at comments@ArtScroll.com

Comment: Wouldn't they translate the Mishneh Torah before the Kesef

Comment: @sam they could make it like rashi style with Mishne Torah at top and Kesef Mishna/Maggid Mishna at the bottom.

Comment: i doubt artscroll would translate any one commentary from mishna torah, probably not even all of them together, because they don't all comment on everything; not by a long shot.